# Ruby on rails - add exception stack trace to 500 error page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 application, currently when an internal error occurs it displays one of the pages listed in:

```
./views/exceptions/internal_server_error.html.haml
./views/exceptions/internal_server_error.json.erb
```

How can I get the HTML 500 error page to display a stack trace of the exception?  I am running Apache not Webrick and I want the exception to display in both production and dev. modes, as this is an internal app.  I tried displaying @exception in the internal_server_error.html.haml page but it wasn't populated.

Comment: Is this in production or development environment?

Comment: I would assume production environment since the default webrick shows the errors.

Comment: I want it in both production and dev., we use apache as the front end.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to show the full stack trace in production, comment out the following line in your `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

It's a pretty poorly named [configuration option](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration), but that is what Rails uses to determine whether or not to wire up the exception handling middleware.

Comment: I want to test this out in development mode first, my development.rb line contains "config.consider_all_requests_local       = true", does that mean the exception middleware is in place for my dev. builds?  I have a custom 500 page generated by the "/views/exceptions/internal_server_error.html.haml" file, all I'd like to do is display the exception name and stacktrace there.

Comment: The middleware bashes over any static 500 file you have defined.  This is the standard exception page you get in development mode already

Comment: I already have "config.consider_all_requests_local = true" in development.rb and never get stack traces on errors, I am always re-directed to "/views/exceptions/internal_server_error.html.haml" which in my case only shows some text, no exception information.

Comment: Which version of rails are you running?  That's definitely not default behavior in Rails 3 :(

Comment: Also, since it's rendering a haml, I'm assuming that you placed that view template in manually?  Try removing it.  The exception handling middleware might look to it for an override

Comment: Your exception _should_ be getting piped through the [`ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb) middleware

Comment: My app is rails-3.2.2.  I removed the views/exceptions/internal_server_error.html.haml file and triggered an exception in the app. but now it's displaying public/500.html.  Is there any way I can add the exception information to that page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23869/discussion-between-fred-basset-and-nevir)

Answer (score 1):

It only worked for us when we set the value to `true`, not commenting it out, i.e., `config.consider_all_requests_local       = true`